# How to use AzureADPreview cmdlets in Azure runbook

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-runbook

I'm trying to use Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs in Azure Runbook, but it keeps giving me *"The term 'Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program"* error.

```
``# Connect to Azure with system-assigned managed identity
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context

# Set and store context
$AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext

# Getting tokens for authentication
$graphToken = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
$aadToken = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.windows.net"
Connect-AzureAD -AccountId $azureContext.account.id -TenantId $azureContext.tenant.id -AadAccessToken     $aadToken.token -MsAccessToken $graphToken.token
- **Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs -Filter "ActivityDisplayName eq 'Add application' | select ActivityDisplayName**`
```

I did install AzureAD and AzureADPreview modules in the Automation Account, and that cmdlet is listed there. I can also use get-azureaduser, but none of the cmdletes from AzureADPreview are working.

Comment: Check the PSModulePath and see if the cmdlet path is in the environmental variable.  From start button type : Edit environmental variable

Comment: It works on my PC, but it doesn't work in Azure Runbook (Automation Accounts)

Comment: What version of Azure are you using?  Se following. If different version change version in upper left corner of webpage : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvm?view=azps-9.4.0

Comment: I'm using Powershell runtime version 5.1

Answer (score 0):

It seems like regular "Import-Module -Name AzureADPreview" does the job.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In your Automation account go to **Modules** > **Add a module**
[image]

Then, Select **Browse from gallery** and **Click here to browse from gallery**
[image]

Look for **"AzureADPreview"** and then click over the module
[image]

Then, click on **Select**
[image]

After that, select the **Runtime version**, and then, **Import**
[image]

Then you should wait until the import is complete
[image]
[image]

After that you an use your AzureADPreview module

Hope this helps!